# Enable iphone 6 resolution not enabling iphone 6 plus

Tags: ios, ios8, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

I am trying to support iPhone 6 resolution without supporting iphone 6 plus yet.
What I tried already is to add launch image for iphone 6 - Image.xcassets called Retina HD 4.7. Unfortunatelly simulator for 6 plus is reporting 2208x1242 screen size (already multiplied by 3). So 6 plus is supported with just 6 launch image.
I am wondering if its just a simulator bug or the same behavior is on actual iphone 6 plus device - I do not have access to such device yet.

Funny thing: when I added just launch images for 6 plus then simulator for 6 is not starting in 1334x750, instead its 960x640 (when retina 4 launch image is not provided) or 640x1136 (otherwise).

Anyone knows how to support just iPhone 6 resolution not iphone 6 plus?

Comment: Looking for an answer for this well. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Not yet. However I have access to physical devices now and I will be searching for a sloution after holidays. I will post my findings.

Comment: Any updates on this issue? I'm in the same boat.

Comment: I did not find any solution for that.
I can just confirm that exactly the same bahavior I've noticed on real devices.