# Use "375x667" in iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

My app is designed for iPhone 6 (375x667).
How can it auto scales to iPhone 6 plus?
i.e, still using frame (375x667) in the iPhone 6 plus screen

Thanks.

Comment: You can't. There is no way to have an iPhone 6 app auto-scale on the iPhone 6+. Only iPhone 5 apps will auto-scale to the two larger devices if you don't support either iPhone 6/6+.

Comment: @rmaddy: Sure? iPhone 6+ does display apps in iPhone6 size when you enable "application zoom".

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26120729/enable-iphone-6-resolution-not-enabling-iphone-6-plus?rq=1

Comment: @Thilo Admittedly I'm not 100% sure but I've never seen a way to do it.

Comment: @rmaddy: This being Apple, I agree that it is likely that this does not work. They are not very big on fallback solutions/graceful degredation/gradual migration and want developers to update all their apps all the way.